# Does Sql Server Compact Edition Support Views?

Tags: sql-server-ce, materialized-views

Does the current version or will any planned future version of SQL Server Compact Edition support materialized views?  Is there a way to implement similar functionality in a way other than straight SQL and table indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know neither the version 3.5 nor 4.0 support any views (and, hence, no materialized views).

Generally as long as you abstract from your database representation you can easily write your own "views" on the code level. SQL CE supports both [Linq-to-SQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2007/08/21/linq-with-sql-server-compact-a-ka-dlinq-over-sql-ce.aspx) and [Entity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494.aspx), the latter provides you with enough flexibility to define your own combined tables that are nothing different like views.

In case you really need a materialized view (that is something unusual to expect from an embedded database) you can just re-create a new table and perform bulk insert using SELECT from existing tables.